# Can I put an ActionListener on a TextArea?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextarea

Is there a way I can set a listener for if the TextArea is edited by the user?

If that is not possible, can I add one to its focus?

Comment: No, `JTextArea` does not support `ActionListener`, as it allows the user to use the enter key to add new lines.  Yes you can add a focus listener, but a `InputVerifier` might be a better choice...

Comment: *"Can I put an ActionListener on a TextArea?"*  Either of the JavaDocs or your compiler could answer that question faster than we can..

Comment: I was more looking for the practical application, @AndrewThompson, like William Morrison gave. Duh you CAN, I wondering practically.

Comment: *"Duh you CAN,.."*  Both JavaDocs and the compiler would suggest otherwise.  Try them if you don't believe me.

Comment: AND that was a misquote.

Comment: Umm... you actually can. Look at the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the document the text area is using via [textArea.getDocument()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDocument%28%29)

Then write a [document listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).  The document listener will tell you whenever the user edits the text area.

Comment: Glad to hear that @IsaiahTaylor please accept this answer to close the  question.

Comment: i will after the 15 mins. dumb policy imho

Comment: Ok thanks.  I wasn't aware of that limitation.

Comment: How do you have 5000 points and not know? Not being offensive, just really curious. Seems like you would have come across that by now.

Comment: haha, no offense taken @IsaiahTaylor! I don't ask many questions, and the ones I do are tough or obscure enough they're not answered in 15 minutes.